# How to make Raspbian recognize SPI input from ADC as a soundcard

Tags: raspberry-pi, driver, raspbian, device-tree, adc

I have an analog to digital converter (ADC) MCP3008 connected to Raspberry PI 4 via SPI interface.
I need to process the signal from ADC in ODAS library (Open embeddeD Audition System).
ODAS is capable to process signal from a device in real time, but requires the device to be a soundcard.
Therefore I need to make Raspbian recognize SPI input from ADC as a soundcard.
After googling I found out that I need to write a device tree overlay to describe the soundcard.
I read about device tree overlays and viewed the device tree specification, but still can't figure out, **which nodes and properties should I describe in the overlay?**

Comment: odas supports 2 kinds of sources: soundcard and file. You can generate PCM stream in one userland app and feed it into odas via named pipe.

Comment: You might want to google for sample code, such as https://github.com/nagimov/mcp3008hwspi

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny thanks for your comment!
I used the approach with named pipe.